# Where is the ClipboardContent class in JAVA?

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

Though a Java novice, I managed to import plain text from the clipboard (sourced in Excel). It looks like the ClipboardContent class would allow me to import formatted text (html, xml...) but my attempts so far always result in "class not found" for any reference to ClipboardContent. 
I suspect there's an import (or full reference) that will fix this but my references and on-line searches have not been fruitful so far. 
I'll appreciate any clues I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Java has some pretty great documentation online.

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is where you can find anything about that you could need that has to do with basic java's classes.  I recommend going here using a ctrl+F for whatever class you need and click on it.  on that page it will give you everything you need to know about it.

Comment: When I do ctrl+F on that site, "ClipboardContent" (all one word) isn't found on the site.

Answer (score 0):

[javafx clipboardcontent api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ClipboardContent.html)

Make sure you import "javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent" (assuming this is what you need).
Just a FYI - you can run into cases were you find similar or identical named classes in other packages.  If you are using Eclipse IDE, you can hover over an class object and it will provide you a hint on where to import it from if Eclipse has those dependencies.  If it doesn't have it, then you will need to add that dependency (like a jar file) and add it as part of your library.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans. When I enter "Javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent" i get "package javafx.scene.input does not exist."
Unfortunately, I can find the description online for ClipboardContent and its methods, but don't seem to be able to get to it. I don't understand why the javafx.scene.input doesn't exist on my installation.

Comment: I think your comment has me headed in the right direction. I apparently need to be in the Java FX mode within NetBeans in order to access the FX libraries. Thanks to both of you for responding to my inquiry.